# Android - user resizable view panes

Tags: android

I would like to present app users with three types of view simultaneously, these are part of a web page (using WebView) and two separate views containing vector graphics.  It is essential that the user can dynamically adjust the amount of screen real estate allocated to each view as they require (in each of horizontal and vertical directions). This is typically done in, say, JPanel by dragging an edge of a view (pane).
I have failed to find any capability for this among the usual Android layouts and I would be grateful for any suggestions as to how this might be solved.

Answer (score 3):

> I have failed to find any capability for this among the usual Android layouts

There's nothing like that in stock Android. On a phone, you usually didn't have a need for this, as there was little enough screen space to begin with. And while it makes more sense on tablets, there's no built-in solution.

I have successfully [used `android-split-pane-layout` for this](https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-split-pane-layout).

Comment: Many thanks, I feared as much but I'll have a look at your suggested source.